# Unable to update global variable using javascript on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope, global

I need to update the `price` global variable. I believe it may have something to do with scope. I would appreciate it if you could be of assistance in this regard.

This is the script:

```
var price = 0;

var nextdayClass = $('.delivery1');
var $standardClass = $('.delivery2');
var $pickupClass = $('.delivery3');

nextdayClass.on('click', function() {
               var nextday = $('#nextday').data('price');
               price = nextday;
               console.log(price);
});
standardClass.on('click', function () {
                var standard = $('#standard').data('price');
                price = standard;
                console.log(price);
            });
pickupClass.on('click', function () {
                var pickup = $('#pickup').data('price');
                price= pickup;
                console.log(price);
            });
console.log(price);

cartTotalHTML += '<div>' +
                '<ul>' +
                '<li>' +
                '<div>Subtotal</div>' +
                '<div>' + formatMoney(total) + '</div>' +
                '</li>' +
                '<li>' +
                '<div>Shipping</div>' +
                '<div>' + formatMoney(price) + '</div>' +
                '</li>' +
                '<li>' +
                '<div>Total</div>' +
                '<div>' + totalAfterShipping(total, price) + '</div' +
                '</li>' +
                '</ul>' +
                '</div>';
$('#cartOutput').html(cartItemHTML);
```

Here is the html where i am getting my data from:

```
                <div class="delivery">
                            <div>Shipping method</div>
                            <div>Select the one you want</div>
                            <div class="delivery_options">
                                <label>Next day delivery
                                    <input id="nextday" type="radio" name="radio" data-name="nextday" data-price="9000">
                                    <span class="checkmark delivery1"></span>
                                    <span class="delivery_price">R90</span>
                                </label>
                                <label>Standard delivery
                                    <input id="standard" type="radio" name="radio" data-name="standard" data-price="3000">
                                    <span class="checkmark delivery2"></span>
                                    <span >R30</span>
                                </label>
                                <label>Personal pickup
                                    <input id="pickup" type="radio" checked="checked" data-name="pickup" data-price="0" name="radio">
                                    <span class="checkmark delivery3"></span>
                                    <span >Free</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Here is the html where i am taking my data to:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-2">
                        <div class="cart_total">
                            <div>Cart total</div>
                            <div>Final info</div>
                            <div id="cartTotalOutput">

                            </div>
                            <div><input type="submit" class="button checkout_button"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: What exactly is your questions/issue?

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues here. Firstly `add()` is to add an element to a collection, not to attach an event handler. To do what you want use `click()` or `on()`.

Secondly, `price` is only updated *after* the click event happens, yet your logic is attempting to read it immediately. To address this you need to put the `console.log()` line in that event handler. Try this:

```js
var price = 0;
var $nextdayClass = $('.delivery1');

$nextdayClass.on('click', function() {
  var nextday = $('#nextday').data('price');
  price = nextday;
  console.log(price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="delivery1">Click me</button>

<div id="nextday" data-price="1.99">Next day: 1.99</div>
```

It's also worth noting that you should avoid the use of global variables where possible. A better pattern to use would be just retrieve the `data` attribute which holds the price where it's actually needed and remove the `price` variable completely.

Comment: Hi Rori, thanks for your answer much appreciated.

I need to use the price variable after it has been modified by the function, thats's why i put the console.log() outside of the function.

Comment: You should still not be using globals for that. I can't really offer any alternatives without seeing what your full logic is doing, though

Comment: Hi have updated my post with all the logic, i trust it should make better sense now.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with scope.

Look at your code:

1. You get an element
2. You say that **when** you click the element `price` should be updated (well, you *try* to, you made a typo and called `add` instead of `on`)
3. You look at `price`

Presumably, at some point later, you click the element.

At this point `price` is updated.

You don't look at it again.

JavaScript does not time travel into the past and change `price` before you looked at it the first time.

The record of what the value was *when you looked at it* that is displayed in the console will not change.

If you want to log the value after you click on the element, you have to put the code that does the logging in the function that is called when you click on the element.

```js
var price = 0;
var nextdayClass = $('.delivery1');

nextdayClass.on('click', function() {
  var nextday = $('#nextday').data('price');
  price = nextday; // The window object stuff is a waste of time
  console.log("Clicked value", price);

});
console.log("Initial value", price);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="delivery1">5</button>
<span id=nextday data-price=5></span>
```

Comment: Hi Quentin, i would like the initial value to say 5 instead of 0

Comment: @PG1728 — So set it to five on line one. That would make the button pointless though.

Comment: Sorry we might have a misunderstanding, i would like the output of the code to say:

Initial value: 5
Clicked value: 5

Comment: @PG1728 — So set it to five on line one. If the initial value is 5, then it will say the initial value is 5. You still cannot make JavaScript time travel so that if you click the button then the value before you clicked the button is different.

Comment: @PG1728 — Looks like the same problem. In your original question, you were getting the wrong value when you `console.log`ed it because you were looking at it at the wrong time. The solution is to look at the value in your click handler. In your update, you get getting the wrong value in the HTML because you are updating the HTML at the wrong time. Update the HTML from your click handler function.

Answer (score -1):

Try JQuery `on()` like this, also as I assume your element may be generated dynamically, try to bind the event handler to the body element/

```
var price = 0;
var nextdayClass = $('.delivery1');

$('body').on('click', nextdayClass, function() {
  var nextday = $('#nextday').data('price');
  window['price'] = nextday;
});
console.log(price); //Prints out 0
```

Comment: Downvote isn't mine, but note that you haven't addresses the issue of accessing the global variable